# how to list all tables in qnx qdb

Tags: sql, database, qnx, qnx-neutrino, blackberry-qnx

I am trying to list all tables under qnx qdb in sql. I am not able to get a suitable command. How do you list tables in a database in qdb. I am able to connect to the database but I do not know what tables are currently in it.

Comment: What is the database engine you use ?? What is the command you use in order to connect to the db ???

Comment: qdb. Its a qnx version of sqlite.
I use qdbc -d <database_name> to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get your interactive session, type `?` and hit `Enter`.

A possible alternative is to make a backup of the DB (`qdbc -d <database> -B`), which will give you a sqlite file that you can load using a sqlite viewer and use usual sqlite commands (in this case, `.tables`).